# Manually Changing Glassfish domain.xml for Debug Error

Tags: debugging, dns, glassfish, fatal-error

I have this line of code at domain.xml:

```
<java-config classpath-suffix="" debug-enabled="false" debug-options="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=9009" env-classpath-ignored="true" java-home="${com.sun.aas.javaRoot}" javac-options="-g" rmic-options="-iiop -poa -alwaysgenerate -keepgenerated -g" system-classpath="">
```

If I start the domain there is no error. However I want to get debug feature so I changed this part like this:

```
debug-enabled="true"
```

When I want to start the domain it gives error:

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized,  jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection refused
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:690]
```

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Change

-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=9009

to

-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9009

Comment: One more question vkraemer. I didn't change it manually(server and suspend configs) How they can change?

Comment: @kamaci -- I am not sure how they could have gotten changed.  Are you using GlassFish 2 or GlassFish 3?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what that change achieves ?

Comment: For GlassFish 4.1.2, I changed that parameter under `<config name="server-config">` in `glassfish\domains\domain1\config\domain.xml,  file. It works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Within Glassfish 3.0.1 there are many domain.xml files. You must be sure to modify the one corresponding to your domain like:

```
<GLASSFISH_HOME>/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml
```