# Problems with Debug in IDEA 11.2.usung glassfish3

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, glassfish-3

I had the same problem as [Manually Changing Glassfish domain.xml for Debug Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140168/manually-changing-glassfish-domain-xml-for-debug-error)

Now it works from asadmin

```
asadmin> start-domain --debug domain1
Waiting for domain1 to start ..............
Successfully started the domain : domain1
domain Location: /home/anna/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1
Log File: /home/anna/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log
Admin Port: 4848
Debugging is enabled. The debugging port is: 9009
Command start-domain executed successfully.
```

But I can't debug from ide as it produces the following

> Wrong debug settings

If to click FIX it would rewrite the admin.xml file What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

Default GlassFish debug settings are suitable for remote debugging (not for local), i.e. server is started and is not paused on startup, but just accepts debugger connection at any time.

If you press 'Fix' button the domain.xml will be overwritten by IDEA, but inside the file only the debug setting will be affected. If you don't want to let IDEA overwrite `domain.xml`, you may change the debug settings manually: you should replace `server=y,suspend=n` with `server=n,suspend=y` either in the `domain.xml` directly or with the GF admin console.

If you don't want to affect `domain.xml`, you may use IDEA remote run configuration instead of local one. In this case, you should start GlassFish manually, then connect to it with
the remote run configuration in debug mode (`server=y,suspend=n` should be kept then).

Answer (score 3):

Glassfish says: `Debugging is enabled. The debugging port is: 9009`.
There are 2 variants:

1. You should change your Run/Debug config in Idea and set debug port to 9009. Because default Idea debugger uses 40875 port.
   [image]
2. You should add custom debug options in your glassfish domain1:

   ```
   <java-config debug-options="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=40875" debug-enabled="true">
   ```

   [image]

I started GF server using `start-domain --debug` and now everything is OK!